# What makes an ASP.NET project an application vs library?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am inheriting some ASP.NET code (I am an OS guy, not a web dev (yet ;-)). The solution has been re-factored and there are multiple projects (libraries and asp.net sites) in it. Aside from the libraries, there are two asp.net projects (called MAINSITE and SUBSITE). Only MAINSITE is being used as the official site (as an asp.net site), and MAINSITE has a depency on the code in the SUBSITE asp.net site, but doesn't use the site itself. I am trying to figure out how to clean this up and convert SUBSITE into a library.

My quick question is, whenever I debug the MAINSITE (set as default), it runs two asp.net processes: MAINSITE and SUBSITE. And so, at the very least, how can I avoid this? Is there a quick/temporary solution to this?

My detailed question is this:

What makes an asp.net site an asp.net site? For instance, in C the difference between an dll and exe could be defined (superficially anyway) as the presence of a main, and potential export information for the library (among other things, of course). If I were to convert an exe to dll I might:
1. remove the main code
2. make sure the public interface was correct (and exported correctly)
3. convert the makefile to build a dll rather than an exe.

Can someone point me to some similar steps for asp.net to .net lib?
Maybe:
1. get rid of index.aspx
2. get rid of web.config
3. any *.cs files to remove?
4. how do I change the properties?
5. any gotchas?

Thanks so much for your help.
Details: Visual Studio 2008/.NET 3.5

Comment: Regarding your quick question, it sounds like there are multiple startup projects configured.  Right click on Solution, Properties and then select single startup project with the MAINSITE selected in the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many, many components to make an application run as an ASP.Net application.  However, in terms of your actual Web Application project, there's really not that much difference between it and generic library code except for the fact that much of your code relies on the existence of the HttpApplication runtime.

Any code that utilizes the System.Web (especially System.Web.UI) is going to be suspect in terms of having this dependency.  For example, all the code in page or webcontrol event handlers (Init, Load, PreRender, etc.) relies on the fact that there is an HttpHandler (running inside an HttpApplication) raising these events.   If you run the same WebControl out of a library that's not in an ASP.Net project, none of this will ever happen and the control will be useless.  However, that exact same library would be quite functional if executed in the context of an ASP.Net process.

It really boils down to what process you're running the library in. In most cases, ASP.Net processes are spawned by IIS, although it is possible to host an ASP.Net process in other types of programs as well.

There isn't a simple 5-step process for converting a web project to a library unfortunately.  But as a rule of thumb, webcontrols, .aspx and .ascx codebehind aren't going to convert.

For a more detailed look at what makes code into an ASP.Net program, see Rick Strahl's "[A Low level look at ASP.Net](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/howaspnetworks/howaspnetworks.asp)".

Answer (score 3):

If you go to "File" > "New" > "New Project..." and then click on the (assuming you're using C#) "Visual C#" in the list on the left, you're given the ability to create a "Class Library" project. You can extract all the relevant code to one of these and then reference in in your "MAINSITE".

You will need to reference it in the "References" section of your MAINSITE project and may need to import your library project using the `import` keyword.

Comment: Yup - This will probably be a lot cleaner than trying to convert SUBSITE into a class library.

Comment: That would only work if his "subsite" contains only classes or other "code" files. Things like ASPX and ASCX files depend upon the ASP.NET compile and would probably just be referenced as an embedded resource in a regular class library.

Comment: well he said the "website" part of SUBSITE isn't used, just some of the code files... that's why i suggested this method.

Comment: Ah... then you are correct then. I was assuming such a "subsite" wasn't used as in "deployed", but may have contained user controls that were used by the main site. +1 from me then.

Comment: This is fine, but I am not sure what is NOT relevant. That is, back to the original question, what makes an ASP.NET application a web app vs a library? What is the generic/boiler plate code/properties/config that I can remove?